# LWJGL VBO Generates seemingly random vertices on Radeon HD 6670?

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, vbo

I was working on a block world with a chunking system and I encountered a bug with VBOs. My cube world seems to generate random vertices, but only on the Radeon HD 6670. I'm now wondering if this is my code, LWJGL, OpenGL, the 6670, or its drivers bugging out, and if it is something I can fix myself. I have a few screenshots, though none of it working correctly. I tested it on a laptop with an NVidia card in it and it ran perfectly fine, and I'm currently trying to test it on an Intel HD 3000. Can anyone tell me what I may be doing wrong? It is supposed to generate a sqaure of faces that covers a 16 * 16 * 16 cube grid.

EDIT: It seems to not work with the HD 3000 either, but all fine on the Nvidia card.

Here are the screenshots: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQtUM.jpg

And here's the code that creates the VBO and renders it:

```
private void updateChunkVertexArray()
{

    thisVertices.clear();

    GL15.glDeleteBuffers(thisVBOID);
    GL15.glDeleteBuffers(thisTexID);

    FloatBuffer bufferedTex = BufferUtils
            .createFloatBuffer(buffer.size() * 8 * 6);

    thisTexID = VBOHandler.createVBO();
    thisVBOID = VBOHandler.createVBO();

    for (int i = 0; i < buffer.size(); i++)
    {

        Vector4f thisVec = buffer.get(i);

        float x = (thisVec.getX() + offsetX);
        float y = (thisVec.getY() + offsetY);
        float z = (thisVec.getZ() + offsetZ);

        float posx = 1.0f * size + x * 0.25f;
        float posy = 1.0f * size + y * 0.25f;
        float posz = 1.0f * size + z * 0.25f;

        float negx = -1.0f * size + x * 0.25f;
        float negy = -1.0f * size + y * 0.25f;
        float negz = -1.0f * size + z * 0.25f;

        if (world.getBlock(x, y, z + 1f) == 0)
        {

            bufferedTex.put(texCoords);

            float[ ] frontFace =
            {
                    // Front Face
                    negx, negy, posz, // Bottom Left
                    posx, negy, posz, // Bottom Right
                    posx, posy, posz, // Top Right Of
                    negx, posy, posz

            };

            for (int t = 0; t < frontFace.length; t++)
            {
                thisVertices.add(Float.valueOf(frontFace[t]));
            }

            //bufferedVertices.put(frontFace);

        }

        if (world.getBlock(x, y, z - 1f) == 0)
        {

            bufferedTex.put(texCoords);

            float[ ] backFace =
            {
                    // Back Face
                    negx, negy, negz, // Bottom Left
                    negx, posy, negz, // Bottom Right
                    posx, posy, negz, // Top Right Of
                    posx, negy, negz

            };

            for (int t = 0; t < backFace.length; t++)
            {
                thisVertices.add(Float.valueOf(backFace[t]));
            }

            //bufferedVertices.put(backFace);

        }

        if (world.getBlock(x, y + 1f, z) == 0)
        {

            bufferedTex.put(texCoords);

            float[ ] topFace =
            {
                    // Top Face
                    negx, posy, negz, // Bottom Left
                    negx, posy, posz, // Bottom Right
                    posx, posy, posz, // Top Right Of
                    posx, posy, negz

            };

            for (int t = 0; t < topFace.length; t++)
            {
                thisVertices.add(Float.valueOf(topFace[t]));
            }

            //bufferedVertices.put(topFace);

        }

        if (world.getBlock(x, y - 1f, z) == 0)
        {

            bufferedTex.put(texCoords);

            float[ ] bottomFace =
            {
                    // Bottom Face
                    negx, negy, negz, // Bottom Left
                    posx, negy, negz, // Bottom Right
                    posx, negy, posz, // Top Right Of
                    negx, negy, posz

            };

            for (int t = 0; t < bottomFace.length; t++)
            {
                thisVertices.add(Float.valueOf(bottomFace[t]));
            }

            //bufferedVertices.put(bottomFace);

        }

        if (world.getBlock(x + 1f, y, z) == 0)
        {

            bufferedTex.put(texCoords);

            float[ ] rightFace =
            {
                    // right Face
                    posx, negy, negz, // Bottom Left
                    posx, posy, negz, // Bottom Right
                    posx, posy, posz, // Top Right Of
                    posx, negy, posz

            };

            for (int t = 0; t < rightFace.length; t++)
            {
                thisVertices.add(Float.valueOf(rightFace[t]));
            }

            //bufferedVertices.put(rightFace);

        }

        if (world.getBlock(x - 1f, y, z) == 0)
        {

            bufferedTex.put(texCoords);

            float[ ] leftFace =
            {
                    // left Face
                    negx, negy, negz, // Bottom Left
                    negx, negy, posz, // Bottom Right
                    negx, posy, posz, // Top Right Of
                    negx, posy, negz

            };

            for (int t = 0; t < leftFace.length; t++)
            {
                thisVertices.add(Float.valueOf(leftFace[t]));
            }

            //bufferedVertices.put(leftFace);

        }

    }

    float[ ] tempVertices = new float[thisVertices.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < thisVertices.size(); i++)
    {

        Float f = thisVertices.get(i);
        tempVertices[i] = Float.valueOf(f);

    }

    FloatBuffer bufferedVertices = BufferUtils
            .createFloatBuffer(thisVertices.size());

    bufferedVertices.put(tempVertices);

    bufferedVertices.flip();
    bufferedTex.flip();

    VBOHandler.bufferData(thisVBOID, bufferedVertices);
    VBOHandler.bufferData(thisTexID, bufferedTex);

//And now the rendering code...

public void renderChunk()
{

    //GL11.glCallList(chunkDisplayList);

    GL11.glEnableClientState(GL11.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, thisVBOID);
    GL11.glVertexPointer(3, GL11.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

    GL11.glEnableClientState(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, thisTexID);
    GL11.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL11.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

    GL11.glDrawArrays(GL11.GL_QUADS, 0, thisVertices.size());

    GL11.glDisableClientState(GL11.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY); // deactivate vertex array
    GL11.glDisableClientState(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    // bind with 0 for normal pointers
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}
```

Comment: Nvidia drivers can be extremely forgiving when it comes to passing incorrect information to GL. I would try to clean up a bit and simplify. Looking at how you copy around data it seem you have missed that `public FloatBuffer put(FloatBuffer src)` increments position in both buffers.

Answer (score 0):

Your graphics card is not put in correctly. This happens to me a lot of times. I take my card out and put it back in then everything works fine. :)